# unknown column in field list - division

Tags: mysql

This query will return an error (unknown column numero_propostas in field list). What i want is something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numero_propostas, 
       total as total, 
       (numero_propostas / total) as divisao 
FROM ConsultaArtigos2 AS ca
...
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL query statement you have to use the column name at the place of reference

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as numero_propostas, 
         total as total, 
         (COUNT(*) / total) as divisao 
   FROM ConsultaArtigos2 AS ca
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numero_propostas, 
       total as total, 
       (COUNT(*)/ total) as divisao 
FROM ConsultaArtigos2 AS ca...
```